# Differences in result in two similar functions: finding the key with maximun value

Tags: dictionary, max, bioinformatics

I am currently having an issue. Basically, I have 2 similar functions in terms of concept but the results do not align. These are the codes I learned from Bioinformatics I on Coursera.

The first code is simply creating a dictionary of occurrences of each k-mer pattern from a text (which is a long stretch of nucleotides). In this case, k is 5.

```
def FrequencyMap(text,k):
  freq ={}
  for i in range (0, len(text)-k+1):
    freq[text[i:i+k]]=0
    for j in range (0, len(text)-k+1):
        if text[j:j+k] == text[i:i+k]:
            freq[text[i:i+k]] +=1
  return freq, max(freq)
```

The text and the result dictionary are kinda long, but the main point is when I call max(freq), it returns the key 'TTTTC', which has a value of 1.

Meanwhile, I wrote another code that is simply based on the previous code to generate the 5-mer patterns that have the max values (number of occurrences in the text).

```
def FrequentWords(text, k):
  a = FrequencyMap(text, k)
  m = max(a.values())
  words = []
  for i in a:
    if a[i]==m:
        words.append(i)
  return words,m
```

And this code returns 'ACCTA', which has the value of 99, meaning it appears 99 times in the text. This makes total sense.

I used the same text and k (k=5) for both codes. I ran the codes on Jupyter Notebook. Why does the first one not return 'ACCTA'?

Thank you so much,

Here is the text, if anyone wants to try:
"ACCATCCCTAGGGCATACCTAAGTCTACCTAAAAGGCTACCTAATACCATACCTAATTACCTAACTACCTAAAATAAGTCTACCTAATACCTAATACCTAAAGTTACCTAACGTACCTAATACCTAATACCTAACCACTACCTAATCCGATTTACCTAACAACCGATCGAGTACCTAATCGATACCTAAATAACGGACAATATACCTAATTACCTAATACCTAATACCTAAGTGTACCTAAGACGTCTACCTAATTGTACCTAACTACCTAATTACCTAAGATTAATACCTAATACCTAATTTACCTAATACCTAACGTGGACTACCTAATACCTAACTTTTCCCCTACCTAATACCTAACTGTACCTAAATACCTAATACCTAAGCTACCTAAAGAACAACATTGTACGTGCGCCGTACCTAAATACCTAACAACTACCTAACTGATACCTAATAGTGATTACCTAACGCTTCTACCTAACTACCTAAGTACCTAACGCTACCTAACTACCTAATGTCCACAAAATACCTAATACCTAATAGCTACCTAATTGTGTACCTAAGTACCTAACCTACCTAATAATACCTAAAAATACCTAAGTACCTAACGTACCTAAATTTTACCTAATCTACCTAACGTACCTAATACCTAATTATACCTAATTACCTAATGGTTACCTAAGTTACCTAATATGCCACTACCTAACCTTACCTAAGACCTACCTAATAGGTACCTAACTGGGTACCTAAGGCAGTTTACCTAATTCAGGGCTACCTAATGTACCTAATACCTAAGTACCTAATACCTAATCCCATACCTAATATTTACCTAAGGGCACCGGTACCTAATACCTAATACCTAATACCTAAACCTTCGTACCTAAATACCTAATCTACCTAATGTACCTAAGGTACCTAATACCTAAGTCACTACCTAATACCTAATACCTAATGGGAGGAGCTTACCTAAGGTTACCTAATTACCTAAATACCTAATCGTTACCTAA"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why does the first one not return 'ACCTA'?

Because `max(freq)` returns the maximum key of the dictionary. In this case the keys are strings (the k-mers), and strings are compared alphabetically. Hence the maximum one is the last string when the are sorted alphabetically.

If you want the first function to return the k-mer that occurs most often, you should change `max(freq)` to `max(freq.items(), key=lambda key_value_pair: key_value_pair[1])[0]`. Here, you are sorting the `(kmer, count)` pairs (that's the `key_value_pair` parameter of the lambda expression) based on the frequency and then selecting the kmer.